# Set quantity of different values

Tags: mysql

I'm kinda fresh in SQL and I really need help :)
I have a code:

```
select *
from table1
where action_code_is in ('pink', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green') 
AND group = 'colors'
```

What I want to filter is only values in action_code_is (I have thousands) which I wrote. The main thing is that I want to have only 4 pink values, 5 yellow, 6 blue and 3 green.
Could someone help me? I'm not sure how to see only a set quantity of actions not all values from table.

Answer (score 1):

Use separate queries for each color, so you can specify different `LIMIT` values. Then combine them with `UNION`.

```
(SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE action_code = 'pink' AND `group` = 'colors'
LIMIT 4)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE action_code = 'yellow' AND `group` = 'colors'
LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE action_code = 'blue' AND `group` = 'colors'
LIMIT 6)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE action_code = 'green' AND `group` = 'colors'
LIMIT 3)
```

Note that `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` will result in unpredictable selections of the rows.

Comment: I just fixed a syntax error, see the update

Comment: thanks again! Yes it is worked!!!
But my another situation is that I have a group of agents and them actions are "blue", "yellow" ... I need to filter and see results per every agent. I mean: first agent: 4 pink, 5 yellow and etc., second agent: 4 pink ... I used rank function for that, but now it does not work with union all :(

Comment: You can use joins in the subqueries.

Comment: SELECT *
from (select rank() over(partition by agent order by rand(101)) as rank_nr,* 
FROM table1  AS table1
and action_code in((select action_code from table1  where action_code='pink' limit 4)
UNION all
(select action_code action_code from table1 where action_code='yellow' limit 5 )
UNION all
(select action_code action_code from table1  where action_code='blue' limit 6 )
UNION all
(select action_code action_code from table1 where action_code='green' limit 3 ))
a
WHERE rank_nr<=18

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. I'm not very experienced with window functions, so I can't really help with that. But you should post a new question.